# Best way to find a new row in VBA between 2 workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I’m working on a VBA macro that will read between two workbooks. Each workbook will have x amount of rows. I am trying to look at both workbooks and identify “new” rows, for example:

```
WB 1:          WB 2:
A               A
B               B
C               X
D               C
E               D
F               E
                F
```

Here I would want to identify the row with X as that is the “new” added row.

Is there an easy way to loop thru each set of rows and identify a row occurring in the 2nd WB that’s not in the 1st? I can’t just compare row by row cause 1 new row mismatches the rest of them as seen from the example above. The rows will be the nearly identical across both workbooks minus the newly added rows (if any)

Been out of coding since school, mainly seeing if anyone could bounce some ideas here.

Thank you!

I’ve been thinking since it’s only ever going to be 30-40 rows, I could loop thru and see if WB 2 contains any rows that WB 1 does not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a column comparison without using VBA. Use VLOOKUP function. If function result is #N/A, this is new value, not existing in WB1. You can also use VLOOKUP function in VBA macro. See example:

Test data:
WB1.Sheet1

| row | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

WB2.Sheet1 , formula view

| row | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | `=VLOOKUP(A1;[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;0)` |
| 2 | B | `=VLOOKUP(A2;[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;0)` |
| 3 | X | `=VLOOKUP(A3;[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;0)` |
| 4 | C | `=VLOOKUP(A4;[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;0)` |
| 5 | D | `=VLOOKUP(A5;[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;0)` |
| 6 | E | `=VLOOKUP(A6;[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;0)` |
| 7 | F | `=VLOOKUP(A7;[WB1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;0)` |

WB2. Common View

| row | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A |
| 2 | B | B |
| 3 | X | #N/A |
| 4 | C | C |
| 5 | D | D |
| 6 | E | E |
| 7 | F | F |

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. It’s part a larger macro for work with multiple steps but this is where I was stuck. Appreciate it!